# Excel VBA Macro to Typescript painting cells

Tags: vba, office-js, office-scripts

I have this VBA Macro that does 3 things:

- Paints all cells with values >= 1 on a specific column, as long as the cell is not already painted
- Paints all cells with dates within the current month
- Erases all rows that don't match either of the previous conditions, therefore are left blank

I'm trying to achieve the same on Typescript, so it can easily be run on freshly downloaded reports by multiple users from the Automate tab. This is my VBA code:

```vb
Public Sub Dates()
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim count, i As Long
    
    Set rng2 = Sheet1.Range("T4:T4000")
    count = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    // there's a header on rows 1 through 3
    i = 4
   
    rng2.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTimePeriod, DateOperator:=xlThisMonth
    
    rng2.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(247, 150, 70)
    
    Do While i <= count
        
        // This is to paint the whole row if cell on column "20" already is painted
        If Cells(i, 20).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 45 Then
    
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(247, 150, 70)
            
        End If


        // This is to paint entire rows where the cells on column 14 are => 1 and not already painted
        
        If Cells(i, 14).Value >= 1 And Cells(i, 14).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Then
        
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
            
        End If


        //This is to delete all lines left blank after the painting has happened.

        If Cells(i, 14).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Then
        
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            
        End If
            
        
        i = i + 1
        
        Loop
                    
End Sub
```

Thanks!

I have not been able to find the same functions on Typescript

Comment: “**I have not been able to find the same functions on Typescript**”, what functions exactly?

Comment: I was not able to even get a count of the rows with data (each report is a different length), nor i was able to find a "this month" function mainly.

Comment: You can use the macro recorder to record some of the code you need for your Office Script.

Comment: I Tried with the Macro recorder, but i was not able to find a "this month" action that would adapt monthly with that.

Comment: `ThisMonth` is just a value that's being used for the operation. The operation that's using `ThisMonth` in your code above is conditional formatting. This is located in Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cell Rules > A Date Occurring...

Comment: Yes i can definitely access the conditional formatting rules via GUI. My goal is to create a JS Script so i can run all this 3 tasks at once by running the script. The code above works perfectly, but the user experience of importing the VBA module to each spreadsheet is not ideal. If i can get this code to run on a Script, the user experience is a lot better for running it on multiple spreadsheets